# relationship between different function classes

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, reference-request

I was wondering if there is a survey of relationship between several different well-studied function classes ?

ps - The question may be vague but I am looking for something along the lines of - http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/2008amstat.pdf

Comment: In its current form the question is hopelessly vague. *Which* function classes, for a start? And what constitutes a "relationship"?

Comment: Maybe, you will find this interesting: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/a-type-diagram-for-function-spaces/

Comment: I agree with you Yemon, but I am still thinking what would be a nice way to even organize these function classes. Rob- Thanks for the link. That looks like one good way to organize them. 